# How to set up font style and size for different sections of RMarkdown document?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rnotebook

Let see the following RMarkdown document.

How to set font types and sizes for these two sections, for example:

1 - "Arial, bold, 9pt" for the first section

2 - "Arial Narrow, bold, 8pt" for the second one.

Thanks!

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: pdf_document
---

## 1. First section with "First car name"

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='asis'}
# 1. Data
fist_car_name <- rownames(mtcars)[[1]]

# 2. Print name of the first car
cat(fist_car_name)
```

## 2. Second section with "Data about all cars"

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

kable(mtcars)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use LaTeX code in Rmarkdown. `\fontfamily` for font family: `phv` is *Helvetica* and similar to *Arial* but doesn't need an extra package. `\fontseries` for font type: we use `b` for bold and `bc` for medium condensed (for other values see [this tex.stackexchange answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68747/136969)). The font size we define with `\small` and `\footnotesize` which should [correspond to 9pt and 8pt](https://www.sascha-frank.com/latex-font-size.html). To revert everthing we use `\rmfamily\normalsize`.

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: pdf_document
---
## 1. First section with "First car name"

\fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{b}\small

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='asis'}
# 1. Data
fist_car_name <- rownames(mtcars)[[1]]

# 2. Print name of the first car
cat(fist_car_name)
```

## 2. Second section with "Data about all cars"

\fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{bc}\footnotesize

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

kable(mtcars)
```
## 3. Let's switch back to defaults

\rmfamily\normalsize

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod 
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
````

### Yielding

[image]

Comment: You're welcome @Andrii, please consider to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)